# Is it possible to parallelize this for loop?

Tags: c++, c, parallel-processing, openmp

I was given some code to paralellize using OpenMP and, among the various function calls, I noticed this `for` loop takes some good guilt on the computation time.

```
  double U[n][n];
  double L[n][n];
  double Aprime[n][n];
  for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
    for(j=0; j<n; j++) {
      if (j <= i) {
          double s;
          s=0;
          for(k=0; k<j; k++) {
            s += L[j][k] * U[k][i];
          } 
          U[j][i] = Aprime[j][i] - s;
      } else if (j >= i) {
          double s;
          s=0;
          for(k=0; k<i; k++) {
            s += L[j][k] * U[k][i];
          }
          L[j][i] = (Aprime[j][i] - s) / U[i][i];
      }
    }
```

However, after trying to parallelize it and applying some semaphores here and there (with no luck), I came to the realization that the `else if` condition has a strong dependency on the early `if` (`L[j][i]` being a processed number with `U[i][i]`, which may be set on the early `if`), making it, in my oppinion, non-parallelizable due to race conditions.

Is it possible to parallelize this code in such a manner to make the `else if` only be executed if the earlier `if` has already completed?

Comment: (LU decomp.?) You can compute the upper and lower triang. mat. individually, yes. But how large is `n`? OpenMP has a very large overhead and I doubt you'll see much below a magnitude of roughly  n = 1e3 .

Comment: Are `U`, `L`, and `Aprime` global scope or function scope? This makes a difference with `openmp`. There are multithread atomic update considerations, but `openmp` has tools to deal with that. So, can you post just a wee bit more code? Also, you have some invariants, so it looks like some restructuring can make this more parallelizable. By splitting things up, you can move/remove the `if` from the `j` loop. Also, what are the values for `n`. IMO, it _can_ be parallelized

Comment: Before deciding to parallelize something, start with finding out if the code makes any sense in the first place. If the code contains nothing but 1 letter variables, performance is likely the the least of your problems. Start with fixing readability, then fix any bugs - likely a couple of them will surface when digging through such crap code. For example, cache performance will be non-existent with this code, to the point where it should be considered a bug.

Comment: @deamentiaemundi yes, LU decomp ;-) n may be up to 4096 so it takes some good time to compute

Comment: @user2018675 it would be nice if you could drop some numbers "before" and "after" (Unix's `time` is enough here), especially with the memory-access optimizations. I have found an old version of mine that was not able to take advantage of simple(!) parallelizing (ca 10% off only) and I suspect a bad memory access to be the culprit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Before trying to parallelize things, try simplification first.

For example, the `if` can be completely eliminated.

Also, the code is accessing the matrixes in a way that causes *worst* cache performance. That may be the *real* bottleneck.

*Note:* In update #3 below, I did benchmarks and the cache friendly version `fix5`, from update #2, outperforms the original by 3.9x.

I've cleaned things up in stages, so you can see the code transformations.

With this, it should be possible to add `omp` directives successfully. As I mentioned in my top comment, the global vs. function scope of the variables affects the type of update that may be required (e.g. `omp atomic update`, etc.)

---

For reference, here is your original code:

```
double U[n][n];
double L[n][n];
double Aprime[n][n];

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        if (j <= i) {
            double s;

            s = 0;
            for (k = 0; k < j; k++) {
                s += L[j][k] * U[k][i];
            }
            U[j][i] = Aprime[j][i] - s;
        }
        else if (j >= i) {
            double s;

            s = 0;
            for (k = 0; k < i; k++) {
                s += L[j][k] * U[k][i];
            }
            L[j][i] = (Aprime[j][i] - s) / U[i][i];
        }
    }
}
```

---

The `else if (j >= i)` was unnecessary and could be replaced with just `else`. But, we can split the `j` loop into two loops so that neither needs an `if/else`:

```
// fix2.c -- split up j's loop to eliminate if/else inside

double U[n][n];
double L[n][n];
double Aprime[n][n];

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
        double s = 0;
        for (k = 0; k < j; k++)
            s += L[j][k] * U[k][i];
        U[j][i] = Aprime[j][i] - s;
    }

    for (; j < n; j++) {
        double s = 0;
        for (k = 0; k < i; k++)
            s += L[j][k] * U[k][i];
        L[j][i] = (Aprime[j][i] - s) / U[i][i];
    }
}
```

---

`U[i][i]` is invariant in the second `j` loop, so we can presave it:

```
// fix3.c -- save off value of U[i][i]

double U[n][n];
double L[n][n];
double Aprime[n][n];

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
        double s = 0;
        for (k = 0; k < j; k++)
            s += L[j][k] * U[k][i];
        U[j][i] = Aprime[j][i] - s;
    }

    double Uii = U[i][i];

    for (; j < n; j++) {
        double s = 0;
        for (k = 0; k < i; k++)
            s += L[j][k] * U[k][i];
        L[j][i] = (Aprime[j][i] - s) / Uii;
    }
}
```

---

The access to the matrixes is done in probably the worst way for cache performance. So, if the assignment of dimensions can be flipped, a substantial savings in memory access can be achieved:

```
// fix4.c -- transpose matrix coordinates to get _much_ better memory/cache
// performance

double U[n][n];
double L[n][n];
double Aprime[n][n];

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
        double s = 0;
        for (k = 0; k < j; k++)
            s += L[k][j] * U[i][k];
        U[i][j] = Aprime[i][j] - s;
    }

    double Uii = U[i][i];

    for (; j < n; j++) {
        double s = 0;
        for (k = 0; k < i; k++)
            s += L[k][j] * U[i][k];
        L[i][j] = (Aprime[i][j] - s) / Uii;
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> In the Op's first k-loop its `k<j` and in the 2nd `k<i` don't you have to fix that?

Yes, I've fixed it. It was too ugly a change for `fix1.c`, so I removed that and applied the changes to `fix2-fix4` where it was easy to do.

---

**UPDATE #2:**

> These variables are all local to the function.

If you mean they are function scoped [*without* `static`], this says that the matrixes can't be *too* large because, unless the code increases the stack size, they're limited to the stack size limit (e.g. 8 MB)

Although the matrixes appeared to be VLAs [because `n` was lowercase], I ignored that. You may want to try a test case using fixed dimension arrays as I believe they may be faster.

Also, if the matrixes are function scope, and want to parallelize things, you'd probably need to do (e.g.) `#pragma omp shared(Aprime) shared(U) shared(L)`.

The biggest drag on cache were the loops to calculate `s`. In `fix4`, I was able to make access to `U` cache friendly, but `L` access was poor.

> I'd need to post a whole lot more if I did include the external context

I guessed as much, so I did the matrix dimension swap speculatively, not knowing how much other code would need changing.

I've created a new version that changes the dimensions on `L` back to the original way, but keeping the swapped versions on the other ones. This provides the best cache performance for all matrixes. That is, the inner loop for most matrix access is such that each iteration is incrementing along the cache lines.

In fact, give it a try. It may improve things to the point where parallel isn't needed. I suspect the code is memory bound anyway, so parallel might not help as much.

```
// fix5.c -- further transpose to fix poor performance on s calc loops
//
// flip the U dimensions back to original

double U[n][n];
double L[n][n];
double Aprime[n][n];

double *Up;
double *Lp;
double *Ap;

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    Ap = Aprime[i];
    Up = U[i];

    for (j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
        double s = 0;
        Lp = L[j];
        for (k = 0; k < j; k++)
            s += Lp[k] * Up[k];
        Up[j] = Ap[j] - s;
    }

    double Uii = Up[i];

    for (; j < n; j++) {
        double s = 0;
        Lp = L[j];
        for (k = 0; k < i; k++)
            s += Lp[k] * Up[k];
        Lp[i] = (Ap[j] - s) / Uii;
    }
}
```

Even if you really need the original dimensions, depending upon the other code, you might be able to transpose going in and transpose back going out. This would keep things the same for other code, but, if this code is truly a bottleneck, the extra transpose operations might be small enough to merit this.

---

**UPDATE #3:**

I've run benchmarks on all the versions. Here are the elapsed times and ratios relative to original for `n` equal to 1037:

```
orig: 1.780916929 1.000x
fix1: 3.730602026 0.477x
fix2: 1.743769884 1.021x
fix3: 1.765769482 1.009x
fix4: 1.762100697 1.011x
fix5: 0.452481270 3.936x
```

Higher ratios are better.

Anyway, this is the limit of what I can do. So, good luck ...

Comment: In the Op's first k-loop its `k<j` and in the 2nd `k<i` don't you have to fix that?

Comment: @Surt Oops, you are correct. I missed that. I'll fix it. That's one of the reasons I decided to "show my work" in stages :-)

Comment: @Surt I just updated, so have a look. Yes, OP's code may need some fixing. I'm just doing the simplification as prep for OP inserting the `omp` stuff, since OP was saying that the code couldn't be parallelized because of race conditions. But, `openmp` has stuff to handle races. Dunno. And, anyway, good catch ...

Comment: @CraigEstey thank you for your feedback. These variables are all local to the function. I didn't post more because the code is kinda messy and I'd need to post a whole lot more if I did include the external context. Thank you for doing it step by step, you did help me to think outside the box on this one ;-) as I'm not the one who wrote this I was being way too cautious you know. Will get back to work now. Thanks!