# OpenCL: Local Memory faster than L1 Cache on CPU?

Tags: c, caching, opencl, gpu, gpgpu

I wrote an OpenCL kernel that performs a box blur on an input matrix. The implementation was originally written for a GPU, and uses local memory to store the neighborhoods of work items in a work group. Then, I ran the kernel on a CPU and compared the running times to an implemenation which relied on caching reads from global memory automatically instead of manually storing them in local memory first.

Under the assumption that a CPU has no "local memory" and instead uses RAM, using local memory on a CPU should do more harm than good. However, the "local memory" kernel was **faster** than the one that relied on caching by 10ms (~112ms vs. ~122ms on a 8192x8192 matrix with Work Item / Work Group / "number of values calculated by each work item" settings deemed optimal for both implementations since they were found by an auto-tuner for both kernels separately).

The kernels were run on a *Intel Xeon E5-1620 v2* CPU using an OpenCL intel platform available on the host.

**What are reasons for this to happen**?

*"Local Memory"* kernel: Each work item works on a "block" of values. Each block is copied to shared memory, and its neighborhood is copied to local memory depending on where the block is in the work group so no values are copied twice. Then, after the barrier, the final value is calculated. 
The code below is the X-direction kernel; the y-direction kernel is exactly the same except for the direction in which the values are inspect to calculate the output value.

```
__kernel void boxblur_x (__read_only __global float* image,
                   __local float* localmem,
                   __write_only __global float* output)
{
// size of input and output matrix
int MATRIX_SIZE_Y = IMAGE_HEIGHT;
int MATRIX_SIZE_X = IMAGE_WIDTH;
int MATRIX_SIZE   = MATRIX_SIZE_Y  * MATRIX_SIZE_X;

// mask size
int S_L = MASK_SIZE_LEFT;
int S_U = 0;
int S_R = MASK_SIZE_RIGHT;
int S_D = 0;
int SHAPE_SIZE_Y = S_U + S_D + 1;
int SHAPE_SIZE_X = S_L + S_R + 1;
int SHAPE_SIZE = SHAPE_SIZE_Y * SHAPE_SIZE_X;

// tuning parameter
// ---------------------------------------------------------------
//work items in y/x dimension per work group
int NUM_WI_Y = get_local_size(1);
int NUM_WI_X = get_local_size(0);

//size of blocks
int BLOCKHEIGHT = X_BLOCKHEIGHT;
int BLOCKWIDTH = X_BLOCKWIDTH;

//position in matrix
int GLOBAL_POS_X = get_global_id(0) * BLOCKWIDTH;
int GLOBAL_POS_Y = get_global_id(1) * BLOCKHEIGHT;

//localMemory size
int LOCALMEM_WIDTH = S_L + NUM_WI_X * BLOCKWIDTH + S_R;

//position in localmem
int LOCAL_POS_X = S_L + get_local_id(0) * BLOCKWIDTH;
int LOCAL_POS_Y = S_U + get_local_id(1) * BLOCKHEIGHT;


// copy values to shared memory
for (int i = 0; i < BLOCKHEIGHT; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < BLOCKWIDTH; j++)
    {
        localmem[(LOCAL_POS_X + j) + (LOCAL_POS_Y + i) * LOCALMEM_WIDTH] = image[GLOBAL_POS_X + j + (GLOBAL_POS_Y + i) * MATRIX_SIZE_X];
    }
}

// only when all work items have arrived here,
// computation continues - otherwise, not all needed
// values might be available in local memory
barrier (CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);


for (int i = 0; i < BLOCKHEIGHT; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < BLOCKWIDTH; j++)
    {
        float sum = 0;
        for (int b = 0; b <= S_L + S_R; b++)
        {
            sum += localmem[(get_local_id(0) * BLOCKWIDTH + j + b) + (get_local_id(1) * BLOCKHEIGHT + i) * LOCALMEM_WIDTH];
        }

        // divide by size of mask
        float pixelValue = sum / SHAPE_SIZE;

        // write new pixel value to output image
        output[GLOBAL_POS_X + j + ((GLOBAL_POS_Y + i) * get_global_size(0) * BLOCKWIDTH)] = pixelValue;
    }
}
}
```

"L1 Caching kernel": Despite the many defines, it does exactly the same, but relies on global memory caching of the blocks instead of explicitly managing local memory.

```
#define WG_BLOCK_SIZE_Y ( OUTPUT_SIZE_Y / NUM_WG_Y )
#define WG_BLOCK_SIZE_X ( OUTPUT_SIZE_X / NUM_WG_X )

#define WI_BLOCK_SIZE_Y ( WG_BLOCK_SIZE_Y / NUM_WI_Y )
#define WI_BLOCK_SIZE_X ( WG_BLOCK_SIZE_X / NUM_WI_X )

#define WG_BLOCK_OFFSET_Y ( WG_BLOCK_SIZE_Y * WG_ID_Y )
#define WG_BLOCK_OFFSET_X ( WG_BLOCK_SIZE_X * WG_ID_X )

#define WI_BLOCK_OFFSET_Y ( WI_BLOCK_SIZE_Y * WI_ID_Y )
#define WI_BLOCK_OFFSET_X ( WI_BLOCK_SIZE_X * WI_ID_X )

#define NUM_CACHE_BLOCKS_Y ( WI_BLOCK_SIZE_Y / CACHE_BLOCK_SIZE_Y )
#define NUM_CACHE_BLOCKS_X ( WI_BLOCK_SIZE_X / CACHE_BLOCK_SIZE_X )

#define CACHE_BLOCK_OFFSET_Y ( CACHE_BLOCK_SIZE_Y * ii )
#define CACHE_BLOCK_OFFSET_X ( CACHE_BLOCK_SIZE_X * jj )

#define reorder(j)     ( ( (j) / WI_BLOCK_SIZE_X) + ( (j) % WI_BLOCK_SIZE_X) * NUM_WI_X )
#define reorder_inv(j) reorder(j)

#define view( i, j, x, y )    input[ ((i) + (x)) * INPUT_SIZE_X + ((j) + (y)) ]
 #define a_wg( i, j, x, y )    view(  WG_BLOCK_OFFSET_Y   + (i), WG_BLOCK_OFFSET_X    + reorder(j), (x), (y) )
 #define a_wi( i, j, x, y )    a_wg(  WI_BLOCK_OFFSET_Y   + (i), WI_BLOCK_OFFSET_X    + (j)       , (x), (y) )
 #define a_cache( i, j, x, y ) a_wi( CACHE_BLOCK_OFFSET_Y + (i), CACHE_BLOCK_OFFSET_X + (j)       , (x), (y) )


 #define res_wg( i, j ) output[ (WG_BLOCK_OFFSET_Y + i) * OUTPUT_SIZE_X + WG_BLOCK_OFFSET_X + reorder_inv(j) ]

 #define res(i, j)         output[ (i) * OUTPUT_SIZE_X + (j) ]
 #define res_wg( i, j )    res(    WG_BLOCK_OFFSET_Y + (i)   , WG_BLOCK_OFFSET_X    + reorder_inv(j) )
 #define res_wi( i, j )    res_wg( WI_BLOCK_OFFSET_Y + (i)   , WI_BLOCK_OFFSET_X    + (j)            )
 #define res_cache( i, j ) res_wi( CACHE_BLOCK_OFFSET_Y + (i), CACHE_BLOCK_OFFSET_X + (j)            )


float f_stencil( __global float* input, int ii, int jj, int i, int j )
{
  // indices
  const int WG_ID_X = get_group_id(0);
  const int WG_ID_Y = get_group_id(1);

  const int WI_ID_X = get_local_id(0);
  const int WI_ID_Y = get_local_id(1);

  // computation
  float sum = 0;
  for( int y = 0 ; y < SHAPE_SIZE_Y ; ++y )
    for( int x = 0 ; x < SHAPE_SIZE_X ; ++x)
       sum += a_cache(i, j, y, x);

  return sum / SHAPE_SIZE;
}

__kernel void stencil( __global float* input,
                       __global float* output
                     )
{

  //indices
  const int WG_ID_X = get_group_id(0);
  const int WG_ID_Y = get_group_id(1);

  const int WI_ID_X = get_local_id(0);
  const int WI_ID_Y = get_local_id(1);

  // iteration over cache blocks
  for( int ii=0 ; ii < NUM_CACHE_BLOCKS_Y ; ++ii )
    for( int jj=0 ; jj < NUM_CACHE_BLOCKS_X ; ++jj )
      // iteration within a cache block
      for( int i=0 ; i < CACHE_BLOCK_SIZE_Y ; ++i )
        for( int j=0 ; j < CACHE_BLOCK_SIZE_X ; ++j )
          res_cache( i, j ) = f_stencil( input, ii, jj, i , j );
}
```

Comment: You may want a look at my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39403215/is-it-possible-to-parallelize-this-for-loop/39404247#39404247 It's not openGL but it has similar issues. In particular, your "L1 cache" version may not be all that cache friendly and you're relying on the optimizer [a _lot_] to optimize loop invariants and common sub-expressions. In my example, in `fix5`, note how I'm explicitly directing the compiler with the use of the extra `Ap`, `Up`, and `Lp` variables to precalc the loop invariants.

Answer (score 1):

When you combine "L1 cache" version's loops:

```
for( int ii=0 ; ii < NUM_CACHE_BLOCKS_Y ; ++ii )
 for( int jj=0 ; jj < NUM_CACHE_BLOCKS_X ; ++jj )
  for( int i=0 ; i < CACHE_BLOCK_SIZE_Y ; ++i )
   for( int j=0 ; j < CACHE_BLOCK_SIZE_X ; ++j )
     for( int y = 0 ; y < SHAPE_SIZE_Y(SU+SD+1) ; ++y )
       for( int x = 0 ; x < SHAPE_SIZE_X(SL+SR+1) ; ++x)
              ....  += a_cache(i, j, y, x);
```

and "local" version:

```
for (int i = 0; i < BLOCKHEIGHT; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < BLOCKWIDTH; j++)
        for (int b = 0; b <= S_L + S_R; b++)
            ... +=input[...]
```

- "a_cache" has a lot of compute

> a_cache(i, j, y, x);

becomes

```
a_wi( CACHE_BLOCK_OFFSET_Y + (i), CACHE_BLOCK_OFFSET_X + (j), x, y )
```

and that becomes

```
view(  WG_BLOCK_OFFSET_Y   + (CACHE_BLOCK_OFFSET_Y + (i)), WG_BLOCK_OFFSET_X    + reorder(CACHE_BLOCK_OFFSET_X + (j)), (x), (y) )
```

and that becomes

```
view(  WG_BLOCK_OFFSET_Y   + (CACHE_BLOCK_OFFSET_Y + (i)), WG_BLOCK_OFFSET_X    + ( ( (CACHE_BLOCK_OFFSET_X + (j)) / WI_BLOCK_SIZE_X) + ( (CACHE_BLOCK_OFFSET_X + (j)) % WI_BLOCK_SIZE_X) * NUM_WI_X )
```

, (x), (y) )

and that becomes

```
 input[ ((WG_BLOCK_OFFSET_Y   + (CACHE_BLOCK_OFFSET_Y + (i))) + (x)) * INPUT_SIZE_X + ((WG_BLOCK_OFFSET_X    + ( ( (CACHE_BLOCK_OFFSET_X + (j)) / WI_BLOCK_SIZE_X) + ( (CACHE_BLOCK_OFFSET_X + (j)) % WI_BLOCK_SIZE_X) * NUM_WI_X) + (y)) ]
```

this is 9 additions + 2 multiplications + 1 modulo + 1 division.

"local" version has

```
 sum += localmem[(get_local_id(0) * BLOCKWIDTH + j + b) + (get_local_id(1) * BLOCKHEIGHT + i) * LOCALMEM_WIDTH];
```

which is 4 additions + 3 multiplications but no modulo and no division.

- "L1 cache" version needs to keep loop counters for 6 loops and they could be using more cpu-registers or even L1 cache. Data cache size is 128 kB per core or 64 kB per thread. If you launch 1024 threads per core(each core is a work group right?) then 1024 * 6 * 4 = 24kB L1 is needed just for loop counters. This leaves 40kB to use. When you add "const int WG_ID_X" and other variables (5 of them), only 20kB is left. Now add the "f_stencil" functions temporary "stack" variables for its arguments, there may be no L1 cache left, decreasing efficiency. "local" version has about 10-12 variables used(not-used variables maybe optimized out?) and no functions so it may be better for L1.

https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/540486

saying

> To reduce the overhead of maintaining a workgroup, you should create
>   work-groups that are as large as possible, which means 64 and more
>   work-items. **One upper bound is the size of the accessed data set** as it
>   is better **not to exceed the size of the L1 cache in a single work**
>   group.

and

> If your kernel code contains the barrier instruction, the issue of
>   work-group size becomes a tradeoff. The more local and private memory
>   each work-item in the work-group requires, the smaller the optimal
>   work-group size is. The reason is that **a barrier also issues copy
>   instructions for the total amount of private and local memory** used by
>   all work-items in the work-group in the work-group since the **state of
>   each work-item that arrived at the barrier is saved** before proceeding
>   with another work-item.

you have only 1 barrier in "local" version and before that point, 8 variables are used so not much memory needed to copy?

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I'll need some time to think about it, but I think you made a pretty good point I previously hadn't thought about.

Comment: But I could also be totally wrong if Intel's compiler keeps all those data in instruction cache(i don't know if thats possible) except the array itself.(What is the number of total bytes of array accessed per thread? )

Comment: The input matrix is 8192x8192, the used settings for the "L1 Cache" kernel were: 

16x8192 Work Groups
512x1 Work Items
1x1 Array Values per Work Item

Comment: The mask/neighborhood size used for the kernel was 15x15, so each work item/thread should be acccessing 225 array elements. The array stores floats, so this amounts to 225 * 4 = 900 Bytes per thread, if I haven't made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: And multiplication by 512x1 gives nearly 450 kB so it is partially L2 maybe?