# openmp increasing number of threads increases the execution time

Tags: c++, c, openmp

I'm implementing sparse matrices multiplication(type of elements `std::complex`) after converting them to `CSR`(compressed sparse row) format and I'm using openmp for this, but what I noticed that increasing the number of threads doesn't necessarily increase the performance, sometimes is totally the opposite! why is that the case? and what can I do to solve the issue?

```
typedef std::vector < std::vector < std::complex < int >>> matrix;

struct CSR {
    std::vector<std::complex<int>> values; //non-zero values
    std::vector<int> row_ptr; //pointers of rows
    std::vector<int> cols_index; //indices of columns
    int rows; //number of rows
    int cols; //number of columns
    int NNZ; //number of non_zero elements
};

const matrix multiply_omp (const CSR& A,
    const CSR& B,const unsigned int num_threds=4) {
    if (A.cols != B.rows)
        throw "Error";
    CSR B_t = sparse_transpose(B);
    omp_set_num_threads(num_threds);
    matrix result(A.rows, std::vector < std::complex < int >>(B.cols, 0));
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        int i, j, k, l;
        #pragma omp for
        for (i = 0; i < A.rows; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < B_t.rows; j++) {
                std::complex < int > sum(0, 0);
                for (k = A.row_ptr[i]; k < A.row_ptr[i + 1]; k++)
                    for (l = B_t.row_ptr[j]; l < B_t.row_ptr[j + 1]; l++)
                        if (A.cols_index[k] == B_t.cols_index[l]) {
                            sum += A.values[k] * B_t.values[l];
                            break;
                        }
                if (sum != std::complex < int >(0, 0)) {
                    result[i][j] += sum;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "sometimes"? For certain input or just randomly?

Comment: How many cores do you have? Switching between threads has a resource cost.

Comment: Are you memory bound (vs. compute bound)? It appears that you are memory bound because fetching the two arrays will take longer than the multiply. Thus, you could saturate the memory bus. On a practical system, this can happen after the number of threads is four or greater (e.g.).

Comment: _Side note:_ In your inner loop, `k` is invariant, so `A.cols_index[k]` and `A.values[k]` are invariant. The compiler optimizer _might_ realize this with a simple array, but might not with what you've got. I always try to "help" the compiler [and _myself_] by grabbing the values: `int Ai = A.cols_index[k]; for (...) if (Ai == B_t.cols_index[l]) ...`

Comment: Before trying to parallelize code, I try to make the single processor code as fast as possible. For example, see my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39403215/is-it-possible-to-parallelize-this-for-loop/39404247#39404247

Comment: Start by declaring your `i,j,k,l` loop variables in the loop headers. Then they become private, as opposed to shared the way they are now.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout I agree that `i,j,k,l` should be declared in the loop headers, but they are private, because they declared inside the parallel region.

Comment: How long the parallel loop last? If the function takes less than a 1 ms, you should not expect a significant speed up. By the way, please do not use `vector<vector<T>>` for dences matrices: this is very inefficient (not contiguous in memory). Please use flatten arrays instead. Additionally, the `break` may cause a load imbalance between threads (resulting is a possibly poor scaling).

Comment: How is the distribution of the sparse entries? You use static scheduling. Since the number of entries can differ, some threads may end with much more work than others. Did you try ```schedule(dynamic)``` or one of the other options?

Comment: You can also declare the ```omp for``` as ```nowait```. If the number of nonzero entries is low, the synchronization overhead of two barriers (one after the loop, one at the end of the parallel section) may be significant.

Comment: @JérômeRichard once the loop finds opposite values of ```cols_index``` any more looping will be unnecessary and will slow the function. what should I instead of ```break```?

Comment: @АлбараАбуяассен Using `break` is a good idea. My point was that it can cause scalability issues though. Thus, you first need to check if this is actually the case (dependent of your data). Then, if it is an issue you can mitigate the problem with dynamic scheduling as proposed by Homer512. However, the best is to manually balance the work evenly between threads. However, this it often not easy and here it is very dependent of the input data. Note that sorting often help for this. In fact, here, it helps to write a more efficient algorithm as pointed out by VictorEijkhout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to improve the scaling of this algorithm, but I would use a better algorithm. You are allocating a dense matrix (wrongly, but that's beside the point) for the product of two sparse matrices. That's wasteful since quite often the project of two sparse matrices will not be dense by a long shot.

Your algorithm also has the wrong time complexity. The way you search through the rows of B means that your complexity has an extra factor of something like the average number of nonzeros per row. A better algorithm would assume that the indices in each row are sorted, and then keep a pointer for how far you got into that row.

Read the literature on "Graph Blas" for references to efficient algorithms.